# Easier way to plot multiple Relative Frequencies

Tags: python, pandas

Plotting multiple relative frequencies (sum of bin to be one, not area of bin to be one) was not easier than I thought.

In Method A, We can use weights argument and plotted properly, but it is not intuitive.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000),columns=['a'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(1+ np.random.randn(100),columns=['b'])

# Method A
ax = df_a.plot(kind='hist', weights= np.ones_like(df_a) / len(df_a),alpha=0.5)
df_b.plot(kind='hist', weights= np.ones_like(df_b) / len(df_b),alpha=0.5 ,ax= ax )
plt.title("Method A")
plt.show()
```

[image: MethodA]

In Method B, the part for determining relative frequencies `count_a/sum(count_a)` is easy to understand, but the diagram is not beautiful.

```
# Method B
count_a,bins_a = np.histogram(df_a.a)
count_b,bins_b = np.histogram(df_b.b)
plt.bar(bins_a[:-1],count_a/sum(count_a),alpha=0.5 )
plt.bar(bins_b[:-1],count_b/sum(count_b),alpha=0.5 )
plt.title("Method B")
```

[image: Method B]

Is there another way to get a graph directly from the data without doing the calculations myself?

Comment: The [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) histogram has a function to display percentages. Is this not your goal? `ax = sns.histplot(df_a, x="a", element="step", stat="percent", common_norm=False,)`

Comment: Yes! That's it!!  histplot() with bins=10, I got same relative frequency histograms. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your bar plot is that the width is fixed by default to 0.8. This can easily be adjusted to account for the real width of your histogram:

```
plt.bar(bins_a[:-1], count_a/sum(count_a), width = bins_a[1:] - bins_a[:-1], alpha = 0.5, align = 'edge')
```

and this is the result:
[image]

In this example the bin width is fixed but by providing a sequence you have a more flexible option, which can be used also in the case of variable bin sizes.

A different option is to use seaborn as suggested in the comment:

```
import seaborn as sns    
df_hist = pd.concat([df_a, df_b]).melt()
sns.histplot(data = df_hist, x = 'value', hue = 'variable', stat = 'probability', common_norm = False)
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that the appropriate width could be easily calculated from bins. `width = bins_a[1:] - bins_a[:-1] = np.diff(bins_a)`. Thanks!

Comment: By using histplot() with `bins=10, common_bins=False` I could get the same multiple Relative Frequency Histogram. it's easy and flexible to use. This is fantastic! Thanks a lot!!